# How do I send an email over Telnet using Inbox.py?

Tags: python, email, smtp, telnet

I want to use Inbox.py to create a local SMTP server, and send an email from it through Telnet.

Since the repo lacks a full example, I found in the issues for the repo someone [had specified a full example](https://github.com/kennethreitz/inbox.py/issues/3#issuecomment-5606161) but I can't seem to get it working.

They specify this code:

```
"""
Proxy smtp to a starttls server with authentication, from a local
connection.
"""
from inbox import Inbox
from smtplib import SMTP

inbox = Inbox()

SMTP_HOST = 'mail.example.com'
SMTP_USERNAME = 'username'
SMTP_PASSWORD = 'password'

@inbox.collate
def handle(to, sender, body):
    """
    Forward a message via an authenticated SMTP connection with
    starttls.
    """
    conn = SMTP(SMTP_HOST, 25, 'localhost')

    conn.starttls()
    conn.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
    conn.login(SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD)
    conn.sendmail(sender, to, body)
    conn.quit()

inbox.serve(address='0.0.0.0', port=4467)
```

But I'm unsure exactly what that is doing. I just want to send an email over Telnet with SMTP commands.

If I `telnet 0.0.0.0 4467`, it fails when I specify my data then enter `.`, stating:

```
error: uncaptured python exception, closing channel <smtpd.SMTPChannel connected 127.0.0.1:52779 at 0x10864f950> (<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>:handle() got an unexpected keyword argument 'subject' [/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py|read|83] [/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py|handle_read_event|449] [/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/asynchat.py|handle_read|158] [/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtpd.py|found_terminator|181] [/Users/Desktop/inbox.py|process_message|18])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using the [telnetlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html) standard library specifically for this purpose.

The issue here might be that `handle()` is unable to make sense of the '**subject:** ' when you try and send mail with the manner in which telnet requires, particularly in regards to carriage returns that would normally follow it.

Another thing you can try is to include '**subject**' in your def handle.